# nodemon not working, Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [script.js] [args] See "nodemon --help" for more

Tags: node.js, nodemon, letschat

```
{
  "name": "nodeserver",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "This is a node Server for LetsChat Application",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": { 
    
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "neetu",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "socket.io": "^2.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide some more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

First try to **Install Nodemon** as **Global**

```
npm install -g nodemon
```

As per your **Package.json** details, Run

```
nodemon index.js
```

If still you face issue, Try to add some details like Error Message you get running **nodemon**.

Comment: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\NEETU GANGAWANE\Downloads\Realtime-Chat-App-master'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Node.js v17.6.0

Comment: Go to your C:\Users\NEETU GANGAWANE\Downloads\Realtime-Chat-App-master Directory. 

Open Command Prompt by typing cmd into the folder path at the top of the window to open a command prompt within the folder.

Run  

`npm i ` - Once it Completes Installing all Modules run tbe below

`nodemon index.js`